# Get all the old names of a renamed file in git

Tags: git

I want to check using git if a file was renamed anytime in the past or not, and if yes, retrieve all the old names of the file. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git tracks content, not files. However, there is a built-in way to ask git to try to reconstruct back this history by following renames :

`git log --follow -- <path/to/file>`

([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---follow))

---

So, to get only the list of names the file had, filter your log output and sort it out like this for example :

```
git log --pretty=format:"" --name-only --follow -- <path/to/file> | sort -u
```

where
`--pretty=format:""` inhibits all commit output except for... (see just below)
`--name-only` outputs file names only
`--follow -- <path/to/file>` turns on the rename detection feature mentioned above
and finally
 `| sort -u` sorts the output and keeps only unique entries

---

**Bonus** : the alias

```
$ git config alias.names '!f() { git log --pretty=format:"" --name-only --follow -- $1 | sort -u; }; f'

$ git names file1.txt

file1.txt
file1.log
f1.log
```

Comment: Without parsing the diff for each commit returned by this command, is there a quick way to just get the old names?

Comment: @NasifImtiazOhi My first answer was incomplete, you're right. Edited.

Comment: Note that `--follow` has some limitations. In particular suppose file *F* was previously named both *N1* and *N2* in two different branches that were ultimately merged to produce the name *F* (during or after the merge); at the time that the branches "branched off" from a common starting point the file was named *O* (both N1 and N2 names were invented independently after the split). The `--follow` code can only find either the set (O, N1, F) or the set (O, N2, F).

Comment: Ultimately this is a very hard (impossible really) problem: see the [paradox of the Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus). What does it mean for something to be "the same" file, if all the lines are replaced? So the `--follow` limitations are sort of reasonable. Still, I'd like to have a smarter file-follower.